# How do you check your units current experience in Civ 6?

Tags: civilization-6

I want to know what units are just about to level up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you select the unit, you can see the XP in the tiny bar at the bottom of the unit info mini-display, as circled in red.

You can get a numerical value by mousing over the bar (not displayed in the screenshot): in this case it will read "15 / 45 until level 3".

[image: Picture of unit summary]

There are also medals indicating how many promotions the unit has, as circled in blue. You can mouse over the medals to see what the individual promotions are.